# Google My Business API Python - Build Error - UnknownApiNameOrVersion

Tags: python-3.x, flask, google-my-business-api, google-my-business

I am trying to Update Cover Photo of Google My Business in Flask App. Below is my code to achieve the same.

```
SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/business.manage"]
API_SERVICE_NAME = "mybusiness"
API_VERSION = "v1"
API_KEY = "api-key-here"
CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE = "client_secret.json"
SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/business.manage"]

gmb_app_verify_business_test.credentials = google.oauth2.credentials.Credentials(
    **flask.session["credentials"])

flask.session["credentials"] = modules.credentials_to_dict(
    gmb_app_verify_business_test.credentials)

service = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
    API_SERVICE_NAME,
    API_VERSION,
    credentials=credentials,
    developerKey=API_KEY,
    discoveryServiceUrl="https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1",
)

cover_update_status = (
    service.accounts()
    .locations()
    .media()
    .create(
        parent='accounts/xxxxxxxxxxxx/locations/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        body={
            "name": "IFB Point Cover",
            "mediaFormat": "PHOTO",
            "locationAssociation": {
                "category": "COVER",
            },
            "sourceUrl": "https://www.ifbappliances.com/media/ifb/ifb-point-cover.png",
        },
    )
    .execute()
)
```

This is giving an error: `googleapiclient.errors.UnknownApiNameOrVersion: name: mybusiness version: v1`

I tried changing the version to `API_VERSION` to `v4` and `discoveryServiceUrl` to `v4`. But the error persists.

Documentation Referred so far:

- https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/upload-photos
- https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/accounts.locations.media/create

But nothing seems to work. Suggestions Please.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there.

For `API_VERSION`, you need to set it to `v4`; because the `mybusiness` service is working on v4.

And for discoveryUrl, you need to pass it as following:

```
discoveryServiceUrl="https://developers.google.com/my-business/samples/mybusiness_google_rest_v4p9.json"
```